# Nginx - Load balancing returns 404 on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, nginx, load-balancing

I have installed Nginx for Windows (64-bit) from [here](https://kevinworthington.com/nginx-for-windows/) because the [official](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html) binaries are 32-bit. The aim is to use Nginx for load balancing NodeJS applications. I am following instructions from [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/deployment-guides/node-js-load-balancing-nginx-plus/) where, the [link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/deployment-guides/node-js-load-balancing-nginx-plus/#full-configuration-for-basic-load-balancing) to sample basic configuration file also exists.

The following configuration file works successfully on Linux where `nginx` was installed via Ubuntu PPA. The servers are themselves started via `pm2`.

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

upstream top_servers {
    # Use IP Hash for session persistence
    ip_hash;

    # Least connected algorithm
    least_conn;

    # List of Node.JS Application Servers
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;      
    server 127.0.0.1:3002;     
    server 127.0.0.1:3003;      
    server 127.0.0.1:3004;      
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ip.address;

    location /topserver/ {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://top_servers;
        proxy_set_header   X-Request-Id $request_id;
    } 
}
```

However, this file does not work with Windows. I am getting an error as 'No such file or directory' under the `html` folder of Nginx installation on Windows. I haven't done any such setting for Linux.

Can you please help me convert the above configuration file for Windows?

**NOTE** I don't have a choice - Windows is a must for this project.

Answer (score 0):

So, I over-wrote the contents of `conf/nginx.conf` with the contents shown above. First, I got an error as `"map" directive is not allowed here`. Then, after removing this directive, I got another error as `"upstream" directive is not allowed here"`. I think, the binaries I am using does not support load balancing.